# How to make a stage as an Aplication_Modal stage when its parent stage is fullScreenMode?

Tags: javafx-2

I am trying to use a stage. Stage as Modal Dialog is not working properly, when its parent stage is in fullscreenmode. Its really strange hard to explain this problem with my poor english, When you try to do this, you will see what i mean i guess. Main stage is hiding when dialog stage is open. I am really confused. I hope someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main stage is not hiding, it is pushed back to the endmost in window cascade list order. You can see the main stage after minimizing/closing other non JavaFX App windows. The workaround to push main stage just one step in window order list, could be setting the owner of the modal stage like this:

```
myDialog.initOwner(primaryStage);
```

Try it.

Comment: Thanks. Its worked. But i have another problem about it now. when dialog stage show up, main stage is repainting. (flaş efekti gibi bir şey oluyor. Buarada çok teşekkür ederim.)

Comment: This is a topic of another question or update your question accordingly. Nevertheless I think currently that effect is unavoidable. Alternative way is to change the StageStyle of the primary stage to TRANSPARENT and maximize it to cover whole screen manually, just like an Ensemble sample app.